# Merge the internet-browser tag with the browser tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup

Currently, there is the [browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser) tag with over 500 questions as well as the [internet-browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-browser) tag with just 6 questions.

What do you think of merging the latter into the former, and perhaps creating a synonym?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Merged and synonymized.**

The [browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser) tag already has [web-browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser) as its synonym, and [internet-browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-browser) is not different than both.

While browsing the tagged questions, there are also questions related to "Samsung **Internet Browser**". I took the chance to create [samsung-internet-browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-internet-browser) tag and re-tag some questions to disambiguate them.

Comment: That sounds perfect, Andrew.  Thank you!

Comment: Also, thank you for teaching me a new English word: *synonymize!*